# UML class diagram code generator java

Tags: uml

generates code fron UML diagram when the user inputs data to the UML. it should have inherritance and abstraction. is there any one that can  help me?

Comment: What are you asking at all?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right I think [ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/) should fit your needs.

Furthermore if you are going to develop in Eclipse you can try the [JPA Diagram Editor](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JPA_Diagram_Editor_Project).